# is their a way where i could have 1 input and put them in field in two different table in access

Tags: ms-access

I have been recently creating an access DB based on the scenario of a company collecting water samples. I have two tables,

Samples: SampleId(pk), GeoLocationId(fk), EmployeeId(FK), SampleComment,SampleDate

GeoInfoDB: GeoLocationId(pk), depth, airtemp, watertemp
 i created the relationship 1 to many for both table.

Now my problem is that when I make a form of the two tables, the two GeoLocationId repeats. Since GeolocationId(pk) is autonumber, I want the GeolocationId(Fk) to be the same. Is there a way anybody could do this. So when someone fills in the depth of the water sample the geolocationID(PK) is created but it should automatically enter the value of geoLocationID in the sample database.
[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g17dU.png)

Comment: Please edit your tags.

Comment: @JvdV to what tags?

Comment: @JvdV I presume this is done in excel though (powerpivot to be exact)

Comment: @Rawrplus, I was more hinting to Access to be added in tags.

Answer (score -1):

Leave your `GeoLocationID` and use the [`=RELATED()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/related-function-dax) function to reference the PK column as the FK.

```
=RELATED(GeoInformation[GeoLocationID])
```